# Java Socket request handling

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp, serversocket

I'm attempting to write a simple file transfer program using the **Java Socket** and `ServerSocket` libraries.  I've used these libraries successfully once before, but in this case I seem to have a problem getting the server side to slow down long enough once the connection is made in order for the client side to make a request.  The problem appears to be happening as the main method on the server side enters the second while loop, calls `handleRequest()`, and once in `handleRequest()`, throws a `SocketExeption` error when it tries to read in the client's request. The program does not pause long enough to allow the user on the client side to send a request. I've tried moving code around within the main's second while loop to no avail.  Any help in getting the server side to slow down and listen would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

**Edit:**
Here's the exceptions thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at FTServe.handleRequest(FTServe.java:92)
    at FTServe.main(FTServe.java:218)
```

**End Edit**

Here's my code:

**Server side**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;


public class FTServe {
    BufferedReader stdIn;
    static BufferedReader in = null;
    static PrintWriter out = null;
    static ServerSocket serverSocket;

    FTServe() {
    }

    /**********************************************************
     * Desc: starts on host A, validates the parameter, and waits on port 
     * 30021 for client request
     * Parameters:
     * Returns:
     * @param portNum 
     **********************************************************
     */
    private Socket startUp(int portNum) throws IOException {
        serverSocket = null;
        Socket clientSocket = null;

        //server to listen on port 30021
        //ftserve starts on host A, and validates the command-line parameters.

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNum);
            System.out.println("Waiting for client....");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port: " + portNum);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        //waits for client message and accepts connection (client IP address and port)
        try {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Accept failed.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return clientSocket;
    }

    /**********************************************************
     * Desc: accepts, interprets and handles client requests
     * Parameters:
     * Returns:
     * @param server 
     * @param server 
     * @throws IOException 
     **********************************************************
     */
    public static void handleRequest(FTServe server) throws IOException {

        Socket dataSocket = null;
        String message = in.readLine();
        if (message != null) {
            if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("list")) {
                int portNum = 30020;
                dataSocket = server.startUp(portNum);
                sendDirectory();
            }
            else if (message.contains("get <")) {
                int j = 0;
                String requestedFile = null;
                char letter;
                String prefix = "get <";
                requestedFile = message.substring(message.indexOf(prefix + prefix.length(), message.length()-2));
                //open port 30020 to send data to client
                dataSocket = server.startUp(30020);
                sendFile(dataSocket, requestedFile);    
            }
            else {
                out.println("Invalid command. Please enter 'list' or 'get <filename>:  ");
            }

            dataSocket.close();
        }
    }

    /**********************************************************
     * Desc: sends list of files in directory to client
     * Parameter: String requestedFile, Socket dataSocket
     * Returns: 
     * @param dataSocket 
     * @param requestedFile 
     * @throws IOException 
     **********************************************************
     */
    private static void sendDirectory() {
        String path = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
        File dir = new File(path);
        File[] listFiles = dir.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < listFiles.length; i++) {
            if (listFiles[i].isFile()) {
                String fileName = listFiles[i].getName();
                out.print(fileName + "     ");
            }
        }
    }

    /**********************************************************
     * Desc: sends file to client on port 30020
     * Parameter: String requestedFile, Socket dataSocket
     * Returns: 
     * @param dataSocket 
     * @param requestedFile 
     * @throws IOException 
     **********************************************************
     */
    private static void sendFile(Socket dataSocket, String requestedFile) throws IOException {
        File sendFile = new File(requestedFile);
        if (sendFile.isFile()){
            byte[] fileByteArray = new byte[(int) requestedFile.length()];

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(requestedFile);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
            dis.readFully(fileByteArray, 0, fileByteArray.length);

            //opens output stream and sends file info and file to the client
            OutputStream os = dataSocket.getOutputStream(); 
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
            dos.writeUTF(sendFile.getName());           
            dos.writeLong(fileByteArray.length);
            dos.write(fileByteArray, 0, fileByteArray.length);
            dos.flush();
        }
        else out.println("That is not a valid filename.");
    }

    /***********************************************************
     * Desc: closes server socket
     * Parameter: serverSocket
     **********************************************************
     */
    private void closeSocket(ServerSocket serverSocket) throws IOException {
        serverSocket.close();
    }

    /***********************************************************
     * Desc: Main method
     **********************************************************
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int goodbye = 0; //if goodbye == 1, close client connection; if goodbye == -1, close server socket

        while (goodbye != -1) {
            goodbye = 0;
            FTServe server = new FTServe();
            Socket socket = null;
            int portNum = 30021;

            socket = server.startUp(portNum);

            String message;

            System.out.println("When you wish to disconnect from client, simply enter 'bye'. \nTo close socket, enter 'exit'.");
            BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 

            System.out.println("Connection from " + socket.getLocalAddress().getHostName() + " successful.  \n\nWaiting on client...");

            //gets inputs and outputs from client
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            while (goodbye == 0) {

                server.handleRequest(server);

                //close connection to client if goodbye == 1 because server entered bye
                if (goodbye == 1) {
                    System.out.println("Connection to client closing...");
                    out.println("Connection to client closing...Goodbye");
                    in.close();
                    out.close();
                    socket.close();
                    server.closeSocket(serverSocket);
                }
            }

            //server.startUp();
            System.out.println("Enter 'exit' to close, else enter 'go' to continue listening for client. When server is listening, Ctrl-C will end program");
            System.out.print("Server> ");
            if (stdIn.readLine().equals("exit")) {
                server.closeSocket(serverSocket); 
                goodbye = -1;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The program is closing. Goodbye!");
    }
}
```

**Client side**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;


public class FTClient {

    static BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    static PrintWriter out = null;
    static BufferedReader in = null;
    FTClient() {
    }

    /**********************************************************
     * Desc: initiates contact with server
     * Parameter: iPadd == server IP address, portNum == server port
     * Returns: Client socket
     **********************************************************
     */
    private Socket initiateContact (String iPadd, int portNum) throws IOException {
        Socket clientSocket = null;
        //ftclient starts on host B, and validates the command-line parameters.
        try {
            //create connection between client and server           
            clientSocket = new Socket(iPadd, portNum);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host: " + iPadd + ".");
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: " + iPadd + ".");             
            System.exit(1);
        } 
        return clientSocket;
    }

    /**********************************************************
     *Desc: sends client message to server
     *Parameter: String msg
     *Returns: Boolean true if client message == bye, else false
     **********************************************************
     */
    private boolean sendMessage(String fromUser) throws IOException {   

        if (fromUser.equals("bye")) {
            out.println("Client> " + fromUser);
            return true;
        }
        else if (fromUser != null) out.println("Client> " + fromUser);
        return false;
    }


    /**********************************************************
     * Desc: sends client command: 'list or get <filename>'
     * Parameters:
     * Returns:
     * @param request 
     * @return 
     * @throws IOException 
     **********************************************************
     */
    private boolean makeRequest(String request) throws IOException {
        //ftclient sends a command (list  or get <filename>) on connection to port 30020.
        if (request.equals("bye")) {
            out.println(request);
            return true;
        }
        else if (request != null) out.println(request);
        return false;
    }

    /**********************************************************
     * Desc: saves the file in the current default directory (handling "duplicate file name" error if necessary), 
     * and displays a "transfer complete" message on-screen or sends an appropriate error message 
     * (“File not found”, etc.) to ftclient on connection P, and ftclient displays the message on-screen.
     * Parameters:
     * Returns:
     * @return 
     * @throws IOException 
     **********************************************************
     */
    private void receiveFile()
    {
        //code remains to be written
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FTClient client = new FTClient();
        boolean goodbye = false;
        Socket socket, datasocket;
        String iPadd = args[0];
        String port = args[1];
        int portNum = Integer.parseInt(port);

        //initate contact with server
        socket = client.initiateContact(iPadd, portNum);

        System.out.println("When you wish to exit, simply enter 'bye'.");

        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        //client sends request, then initiates contact with data socket to receive data
        while (!goodbye) {
            System.out.println("Server> Enter 'list' to display a directory of files. \nEnter 'get <filename>' to retrieve a file.  " +
                    "\nPlease enter a command: ");
            String request = stdIn.readLine();
            goodbye = client.makeRequest(request);
            int dataPort = 30020;
            Socket dataSocket = client.initiateContact(iPadd, dataPort);
            client.receiveFile();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: The message is too long so I'll post remainder in next comment:Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)

Comment: That didn't work too well.  I'll edit the original post.

Comment: while (goodbye = false) { should be while (!goodbye) {

Comment: Change made in code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a serversocket everytime.

What you should be doing is on start up create a thread to handle socket acceptances.
The thread that handles acceptances should then hand off any client to another thread.

something like

```
public ServerSocketProcessor implements Runnable{

    private boolean execute;
    private int commandPortNumber;
    private int dataPortNumber;

    public ServerSocketProcessor(int commandPortNumber, int dataPortNumber, SocketHandler socketHandler){
        this.commandPortNumber= commandPortNumber;
        this.dataPortNumber= dataPortNumber;
        this.socketHandler = socketHandler;
    }

    public void run(){
        this.execute = true;
        try{
           // only ever want one server socket and keep it running for lifetime
           // of your program
           ServerSocket commandServerSocket = new ServerSocket(this.commandPortNumber);
           ServerSocket dataServerSocket = new ServerSocket(this.dataPortNumber);
           try {
               // keep running until another process says to stop
               while(this.execute){
                   // accept will cause the server socket to wait until
                   // a connection is made
                   Socket commandSocket = commandServerSocket .accept();
                   // handle new connection then go back to waiting for a new
                   // connection.
                   Socket dataSocket = dataServerSocket.accept();
                   socketHandler.handle(commandSocket, dataSocket);
               }
           } finally{
               serverSocket.close();
           }
        } catch (exception e){
            // do something
        }
    }

}
```

SocketHandler just creates threads to handle the incoming connection

```
public class SocketHandler{

    public void handle(Socket commandSocket, Socket dataSocket){
         // create thread to handle socket
    }

}
```

client side

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FTClient client = new FTClient();
    boolean goodbye = false;
    Socket socket, datasocket;
    String iPadd = "127.0.0.1";
    String port = "30021";
    int portNum = Integer.parseInt(port);

    //initate contact with server
    socket = client.initiateContact(iPadd, portNum);

    System.out.println("When you wish to exit, simply enter 'bye'.");

    out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    //client sends request, then initiates contact with data socket to receive data
    while (!goodbye) {
      System.out.println("Server> Enter 'list' to display a directory of files. \nEnter 'get <filename>' to retrieve a file.  " +
              "\nPlease enter a command: ");
      String request = stdIn.readLine();
      goodbye = client.makeRequest(request);
    }
    client.cleanUp(); // in this you should close any datastreams and close the socket

  }
```

Comment: That's a good suggestion.  However, when I run the code through debugger, I'm not even getting that far.  The exception is thrown at the beginning of the method at `String message = in.readLine();`

Comment: Question about the implementation: I currently call `startUp()` from the main method and then when the client request has been received and I need to open a new socket down which to send data, I call it again by passing in `dataSocket` to open a new socket on 30020.  Just to clarify, are you suggesting that upon startup, I would call a method like `ServerSocketProcessor()` which would in turn call `handle()` in the `SocketHandler` class, but when I need to open that second port to send data to the client, I would only need to go straight to `handle()` in the `SocketHandler` class?

Comment: The `server socket` only listens for connections. Once a connection is accepted then the `socket` you use for the connection is already constructed. You hand it off to the handler because you do not want the `server socket` to have to wait for the socket to be processed before it can accept another one.

Comment: Then my next question is are you suggesting that the `server socket` can be shifted to listen at another port?  I.e. The server "listens" via the `server socket` for the initial connection between the server and the client on port A. Once the client connects, the server hands that socket off to the handler and is now free to shift the `server socket` to listen on port B.  Once the `server socket` accepts the connection at port B, there are now two connections through which the server can communicate with the client?  I hope I'm making sense as I attempt to grasp the ramifications.

Comment: One server socket per port. But you can accept more than one socket on that port at any given time. So you do not need to shift the server socket. you can just keep connecting to the same port this will give you more connections.

Comment: Ah, but the program requires that a different port (30020) is used to send files.  So one port (30021) for client requests, one port (30020) for data transfer.

Comment: I have made an edit to the server, Keeping the two socket streams sane will be a bit complicated and I haven't attempted to do that.